# Is it possible to add an item to the right-click context menu of a Mac OS programmatically?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, contextmenu

I have a program that works with a variety of files on both the Windows and Mac OS.

I would like to give the user the option of adding a new option to their right click/control click context menu to the effect of "Compress with [Name of App]".

I know this is quite possible in Windows with modifications to the registry, but is there a way to achieve this for the Mac? Perhaps using C++ or objective C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to make a contextual menu plugin. Apple has [contextual menu plugin sample code](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/SampleCMPlugIn/index.html) on its developer site.

Comment: That's super - again thanks a lot I will investigate this option too

Comment: I am trying to do the same... but I cannot find that sample anymore ;( Could you update the link please?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a guide: [Writing Contextual Menu Plugins for OS X, part 1](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.18/18.08/MenuPlugins/index.html)

Comment: And the best part it is based on COM. LOL!

Comment: Thanks pixOr, I am trying to do the same, but this is old info and I wonder if this works for Snow Leopard. The article is of 2002!.